# setState in separated component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, higher-order-components

So I'm in the middle of my project and I found a problem that's too complicated for me.
I need to use sth like this:

```
{this.state.isOpen && <MyComponent />}
```

but state that I want to refer to is inside hoc, let's name it AppHOC. AppHOC works with some components that I need to display in Root by clicking on an  but Icon is also separated and it looks like:

```
const Root = () => {
   return(
      {this.state.isOpen && <MyComponent />}
      <Wrapper>
         <Icon />
      </Wrapper>
   );
}
```

So the problem is: App onClick have to setState of AppHOC and recieve one of functions that AppHOC contains, and Root file have to get that state from AppHOC. Is it possible? Can I do it using Redux? Does Redux work with HOC like one reducer but state separated for every generated MyComponent? Should I use HOC here or not?

Comment: It's unclear what's the relation between AppHoc and the component you listed. Redux doesn"t care about component hierarchy as long as components are inside Redux provider, so yes, it can likely help here. It's an overkill if you don't need it in other aspects.

Comment: AppHOC is imported to MyComponent and exported like export default AppHOC(MyComponent); and I'd like to display it inside Root file but only if state.isOpen inside AppHOC is set to TRUE. That's most important problem here. I also want and Icon component to change state of AppHOC component from FALSE to TRUE. Icon is completely separated component and that setState would be the only connection between them. There will be some more Icons and MyComponents and each icon would setState for other MyComponent. I think I'd use something like if Icon is clicked add prop to <MyComponent> with state/func

Answer (score 1):

This is a common case for [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). A common parent should host the state, which seems to be `Root` in this case.

Since passing a state through props to
multiple deeply nested components can be cumbersome, it can be passed through React context:

```
const OpenContext = React.createContext();
const Root = () => {
   let [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
   let openState = React.useMemo(() => [open, setOpen], [open]);

   return(
     <OpenContext.Provider value={openState}>
      {open && <MyComponent />}
      <Wrapper>
         <Icon />
      </Wrapper>
     </OpenContext.Provider>
   );
}
```

The state can be accessed in nested components with context API:

```
let [open, setOpen] = React.useContext(OpenContext);
```

This is a problem that Redux can solve but it's not required.